# Is it possible to use properties file for translation in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, properties-file

I want to add i18n to my project by using intl module in reactjs. I've tried to translate by using json files. I achieved this purpose by using json files. But i want to use .properties files. It was very easy to translate content by using .json files. When i use properties or properties-reader modules i got error as "fs.fileRead is not a function" or "fs.fileReadAsync is not a function!" Is there any way to translate the content if i convert json files to properties files? 
Here is properties file:
    `mainDashboard=Main Dashboard
    el=Entity Library
    cl=Content Library
    elPerson=Person
    elCompany=Company
    elGroup=Group
    elActivity=Activity
    clManagement=Content Management
    user=User user`